# How can I add more values to SAPUI5 vizFrame pie chart on select?

Tags: sapui5

I am using this [sample](http://jsbin.com/salezobimo/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
<viz:VizFrame id="oVizFrame" busy="false" busyIndicatorDelay="1000" visible="true" uiConfig="{ 'applicationSet': 'fiori' }" vizType="pie" legendVisible="true">

    <viz:dataset>
        <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{/book}">
            <viz.data:dimensions>
                <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Item Category" value="{Item Category}"/>
            </viz.data:dimensions>

            <viz.data:measures>
                <viz.data:MeasureDefinition group="1" name="Profit" value="{Profit}"/>

            </viz.data:measures>
        </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
    </viz:dataset>
    <!-- sap.viz.ui5.data.Dataset -->
    <viz:feeds>

        <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="size" type="Measure" values="Profit"/>
        <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="color" type="Dimension" values="Item Category"/>

    </viz:feeds>
</viz:VizFrame>
```

I am not able to add more book properties like City and Profit to the existing pie chart. Please guide me.

Comment: Do you want to add them after the chart is selected ?

Comment: @StephenS before the chart is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly add more dimensions to the pie chart but only one measure will be allowed.

```
<viz:VizFrame id="oVizFrame" busy="false" busyIndicatorDelay="1000" visible="true" uiConfig="{ 'applicationSet': 'fiori' }" vizType="pie" legendVisible="true">
                    <viz:dataset>
                        <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{/book}">
                            <viz.data:dimensions>
                                <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Item Category" value="{Item Category}"/>
                                <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="City" value="{City}"/>
                            </viz.data:dimensions>

                            <viz.data:measures>
                                <viz.data:MeasureDefinition group="1" name="Profit" value="{Profit}"/>
                            </viz.data:measures>
                        </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
                    </viz:dataset>
                    <!-- sap.viz.ui5.data.Dataset -->
                    <viz:feeds>
                        <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="size" type="Measure" values="Profit"/>
                        <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="color" type="Dimension" values="Item Category"/>
                        <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="color" type="Dimension" values="City"/>

                    </viz:feeds>
                </viz:VizFrame>
```